# SQL Server MetaData NVarChar size

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, database-metadata

One of our SQL Server column was recently modified from `varchar` to `nvarchar`, as a result the max_length value in `sys.tables` doubled. In the vb counterpart, our `SQLMetadata` objects were instantiated using the character length of the column, the last parameter of the constructor being the max length.

Should the `SQLMetadata` parameter be changed to use the `nvarchar` max length in bytes or left the way it is (character length of the SQL column)?

```
SQLMetadataObj = new SqlMetaData("Column1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 12)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you mean `sys.columns` rather than `sys.tables`. What you're seeing is the number of bytes, not the number of characters. I just created two columns of type `varchar(50)` and `nvarchar(50)` and `sys.columns` shouwed a `max_length` of 50 and 100 respectively. The documentation for the `SqlMetaData` class that you posted that code example from specifically states:

> The following example creates a new SqlMetaData object by specifying
>   the column name, a column data type of SqlDbType.NVarChar, and a
>   maximum length of 12 **characters**.

That means that you need to provide the number you see in the table designer, not in `sys.columns`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I should have said sys.columns rather than sys.tables. Sorry. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Orion, the `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` column of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view contains the length in chararacters instead of bytes.